# $.extend is not a function with React SSR

Tags: jquery, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, react-ssr

I am facing an issue in react SSR.

Added two plugins which are as under

```
import 'fullcalendar';
import 'fullcalendar-scheduler';
```

FullCalander throwing an error in terminal which is stated below

```
webpack:///./node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js?:1256
var oldMomentProto = $.extend({}, newMomentProto); // copy of original moment methods
                   ^

TypeError: $.extend is not a function
at Object.defineProperty.value (webpack:///./node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js?:1256:24)
at __webpack_require__ (webpack:///./node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js?:30:30)
at Object.defineProperty.value (webpack:///./node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js?:4549:20)
at __webpack_require__ (webpack:///./node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js?:30:30)
at Object.defineProperty.value (webpack:///./node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js?:1754:25)
at __webpack_require__ (webpack:///./node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js?:30:30)
at Object.defineProperty.value (webpack:///./node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js?:12374:19)
at __webpack_require__ (webpack:///./node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js?:30:30)
at module.exports (webpack:///./node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js?:73:18)
at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js?:76:10)
```

I have imported jQuery as well but have no idea why getting the above issue.

Comment: Are you loading jQuery first?

Comment: yes i have already added jquery

Comment: That's not what i asked. In what order do you call your scripts ?

Comment: import $ from 'jquery';
import 'moment';
import 'fullcalendar';
import 'fullcalendar-scheduler';

something like above

Comment: change your jquery import to `import * as $ from 'jquery';` or `import * as jQuery from 'jquery';`

Comment: nothing happens :(

Comment: Did you try call `jQuery` instead of `$` like `jQuery.extend({}, newMomentProto)`. From elsewhere you can use `Object.assign({}, newMomentProto)` from ES6 check https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/assign

Comment: Whatever @GameTag suggested that should work.
In case not can you share you package.json?

Comment: solved this issue by importing scripts only in browser. => 
!is_server() && (require('fullcalendar'));
!is_server() && (require('fullcalendar-scheduler'));

Comment: That doesn't really make sense in the scope of your question, but glad you got it working